# ¿como lograr con javascript capturar texto con una referencia similar a otro texto? Fuzzy Matching puede ser la solución?

Tags: javascript, regex, javascript-metodo, match

Buenas tardes estimados.

He realizado este intento de otros 25 para lograr capturar un título dentro de un texto grande, el cual se puede repetir de distintas formas.
Cuento con una entrada de referencia que es otro título similar al que figura en el texto grande, usando solo regexp no se logra obtener buenos resultados ya que "input" no es exacta a lo que figura en "text" ya sea por tener las palabras o grupo de caracteres ambos separados por un espacio que no están con un orden idéntico a lo que figura en "text", y/o algunas palabras o caracteres no existen en el título de "text".
Esto lo estoy haciendo para capturar luego un precio principal asociado a este título que es otra historia y lo tengo casi resuelto.
Aquí comparto un ejemplo super sintetizado para que tengan una idea, pues me dá resultados no tan seguros y sin lograr obtener el título real en el texto grande:

```
const input = "1000ml gel eco-pack de alcohol";
const text = "capilar ver todo en cuidado capilar shampoo y acondicionador geles capilares tratamientos capilares baby &amp; kids ver todo en baby &amp; kids baby kids salud al aire libre ver todo en salud al aire libre repelentes cocoa beach limpieza y hogar ver todo en limpieza y hogar aromatizantes limpieza contacto nuestra empresa crear cuenta iniciar sesión buscar repuesto alcohol en gel eco-pack 1000ml clínica y dermatológicamente testeado 70% menos plástico presentación 1000ml | código de producto: 6040921| ean-13: 7791274199592 $856,00 3 cuotas sin interés de $285,33 ver más detalles medios de pago mercadopago pagos personalizados tarjetas de crédito 3 cuotas sin interés de $285,33 cft: 0,00% total: $856,00 en 1 pago: $856,00 3 cuotas con otras tarjetas o en 1 pago de: $856,00 tarjeta de débito y efectivo débito precio: $856,00 efectivo precio: $856,00 transferencia o depósito precio: $856,00 volver";

const entradaArray = input.split(/\s+/); // se divide la entrada en un array de palabras
console.log("entradaArray"+entradaArray);
const entradaRegexp = entradaArray.map(word => `(?=.*\\b${word}\\b)`).join(""); // se construye una expresión regular que busque todas las palabras en cualquier orden
console.log("entradaRegexp"+entradaRegexp);
const regexString = `\\b${entradaRegexp}.{10,50}\\b`; // se construye la expresión regular final, que permite que haya hasta 50 caracteres entre las palabras de la entrada
console.log("regexString"+regexString);

const regex = new RegExp(regexString, "gi");
const coincidencias = text.match(regex);
console.log(coincidencias);
```

y en consola me entrega esto:

```
$ node findTitle.js
entradaArray1000ml,gel,eco-pack,de,alcohol
entradaRegexp(?=.*\b1000ml\b)(?=.*\bgel\b)(?=.*\beco-pack\b)(?=.*\bde\b)(?=.*\balcohol\b)
regexString\b(?=.*\b1000ml\b)(?=.*\bgel\b)(?=.*\beco-pack\b)(?=.*\bde\b)(?=.*\balcohol\b).{10,50}\b
[
  'capilar ver todo en cuidado capilar shampoo y ',
  'acondicionador geles capilares tratamientos ',
  'capilares baby &amp; kids ver todo en baby &amp; ',
  'kids baby kids salud al aire libre ver todo en ',
  'salud al aire libre repelentes cocoa beach ',
  'limpieza y hogar ver todo en limpieza y hogar ',
  'aromatizantes limpieza contacto nuestra empresa ',
  'crear cuenta iniciar sesión buscar repuesto ',
  'alcohol en gel eco-pack 1000ml clínica y dermatoló'
]
```

donde el último match es el que se acerca a lo que busco siendo "alcohol en gel eco-pack 1000ml" lo ideal como salida precisa para usarlo luego en otra regexp.

He imaginado otras soluciones implementando arrays tanto en "input" y "texto" como para poder hallar los match palabra por palabra referenciados a un índice y luego juntar los grupos de índices y evaluar cuales matchs tienen menor separación entre índices para inferir que es una frase similar a "input" la más cercana posible. Ni le encuentro una solución robusta.

Aclaro que este es un ejemplo para aplicarlo en otros casos similares donde "input" y "text"  van a ser completamente diferentes y van a mantener el mismo principio que explique al comienzo.

Gracias desde ya por cualquiera que aporte una idea.

Agrego una edición de lo que estuve investigando y me encontré con el concepto de Fuzzy Matching que nunca lo apliqué al momento como junior.

Si hay una idea de como resolverlo dentro del abanico de posibilidades en mi código se los agradezco.

Saludos!

Comment: Estás usando algún tipo de base de datos? Normalmente el "text search" de las bases de datos resuelven ese problema

Comment: Hola @Pipe casualmente nada de base de datos estoy usando, los datos provienen de páginas html extraídos con Cheerio. Gracias!

Comment: Quizas entonces podrias investigar acerca del algoritmo Jaro-Winkler

Comment: Gracias @Pipe si algo de eso me había cruzado de casualidad como concepto, derivado de fuzzy matching. Gracias

Comment: Hola Pablo, has logrado resolverlo?.

Comment: Hola @MarcePuente al momento no, me indicaron utilizar Html2text con python a ver si resulta antes de meterme con esto de fuzzy matching, pues usando cheerio obtenía al final un texto plano para procesarlo con regexp, y ahora me indicaron obtener un texto plano con Html2text para aplicar regexp entiendo que es lo mismo que venía haciendo y como son órdenes tengo que hacerlo a no ser que ya tenga resuelto mucho antes con mi solución usando fuzzy matching y se quede sin palabras el supervisor

Comment: Yo tengo una solución, pero sin regex, es más larga, pero es fácilmente modificable, no se si te sirve.

Comment: Hola @MarcePuente ahí estoy estudiando tu solución, es muy ingeniosa, he visto que utilizaste en "claves" la palabra ```en``` en lugar de ```de```, que no existe en el input como clave original ```const input = "1000ml gel eco-pack de alcohol" ``` es algo que tal vez yo pueda ajustar para lograr la ***coincidencia difusa*** tan difícilmente buscada, tu lógica es interesante y me gusta y es de gran ayuda para guiarme con tu estructura, aparenta tener potencial para ***fuzzy matching***, la sigo desarrollando. Gracias MarcePuente!

Comment: Un placer ayudarte, estuve pensando que podrías hacer una lista de "sin significado", tipo "la, el, de, etc" poner un `if` en el inicio del `for`, que invoque a una función que verifique que la palabra actual, este entre ella, en cuyo caso, pasaría a la siguiente palabra, por otro lado, puedes cambiar el `array` **claves**, por una matriz, donde cada fila, tiene una palabra a buscar y sus sinónimos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let claves = [ "1000ml", "gel", "en", "eco-pack", "alcohol" ];
let texto = "capilar ver todo en cuidado capilar shampoo y acondicionador geles capilares tratamientos capilares baby &amp; kids ver todo en baby &amp; kids baby kids salud al aire libre ver todo en salud al aire libre repelentes cocoa beach limpieza y hogar ver todo en limpieza y hogar aromatizantes limpieza contacto nuestra empresa crear cuenta iniciar sesión buscar repuesto alcohol en gel eco-pack 1000ml clínica y dermatológicamente testeado 70% menos plástico presentación 1000ml | código de producto: 6040921| ean-13: 7791274199592 $856,00 3 cuotas sin interés de $285,33 ver más detalles medios de pago mercadopago pagos personalizados tarjetas de crédito 3 cuotas sin interés de $285,33 cft: 0,00% total: $856,00 en 1 pago: $856,00 3 cuotas con otras tarjetas o en 1 pago de: $856,00 tarjeta de débito y efectivo débito precio: $856,00 efectivo precio: $856,00 transferencia o depósito precio: $856,00 volver";      
   
function buscar( claves, texto ) { 

     // creamos un array con el texto
   let textoEntrada = texto.split( " " );
   let cuantas = 0;
   let primera = -1;
   let ultima = -1;
   let iniciado = false;

     // iteramos sobre el array e invocamos a "verifica", pasando como parámetros
     // el array de palabras buscadas y la palabra del array sobre el que iteramos
   for( let i = 0; i < textoEntrada.length; i++ ) {
      if( verifica( textoEntrada[ i ], claves ) ) {
         if( iniciado ) {

              // si ya hubo palabras encontradas guardamos la posición de la que 
              // sería la última palabra encontrada y sumamos "1" a "cuantas"
            ultima = i;
            cuantas += 1;
         }
         else {
  
              // si la busqueda no tiene aciertos anteriores, guardamos la posición 
              // de la que sería la primera palabra y sumamos "1" a "cuantas" y 
              // ponemos iniciado en "true" para buscar las siguientes
            primera = i;
            cuantas += 1;
            iniciado = true;
         }
         if( cuantas == claves.length ) {

              // si encontramos todas las palabras, creamos el texto de salida, le
              // agregamos la primer palabra (para no tener problemas con los " ", y sumamos "1" a "primera", luego iteramos agregando el resto de palabras
            let salida = textoEntrada[ primera ];
            primera++;
            for( ; primera < ultima +1; primera++ ) {
               salida += " " + textoEntrada[ primera ];
            }               
            return salida;
         }
      }
      else {

           // si ya hubo palabras encontradas, y aparece una que no es, se restablecen los valores
         iniciado = false;
         primera = -1;
         ultima = -1;
         cuantas = 0;
      }         
   }
   return "";
}

function verifica( textoEntrada, claves ) {

     // acá, dependiendo de tus necesidades, podrías implementar un método
     // que quite los acentos y las mayúsculas
   let sinAcentosNiOtros = textoEntrada;

     // iteramos sobre las palabras a buscar y devolvemos "true" si hay coincidencia
   for( let i = 0; i < claves.length; i++ ) {
      if( claves[ i ] == sinAcentosNiOtros ) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}


let encontradas = buscar( claves, texto );  
console.log( encontradas );
```